# Entity Framework Connection Failures Fire and Forget

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, azure-sql-database

I have an action filter that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute in an ASP.NET Web Api 2 environment. In the OnActionExecuted override I call the following:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (!MyCallContext.TimingRecords.Any()) return;
        Task.Run(async () => await DbStore.InsertTimings(MyCallContext. TimingRecords));
    }
```

The aim is to not block the response to the user, capturing the timing telemetry
The call to InsertTimings calls the following code:

```
            _prodActivityDbContext.Timings.AddRange(timings);
            await _prodActivityDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Occasionally I am receiving an error that points to an Entity Framework connection failure.
"ex0.Message": "An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information."
I am using the azure retry strategy using the following:

```
public class SlcsDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SlcsDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }
}
```

The record is always being successfully written to the database, so I was wondering it there is something to do with the fact that it is being fired and forgotten that causes this error to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Fire and Forget is not a good idea at all, but there are some acceptable approaches to get almost the same effect. I particularly recommend a library called Hang Fire (https://www.hangfire.io/). Stephen Cleary presented some other good approches on his blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html